# How do I dynamically add attributes to an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface：

```js
interface Container {

}
```

```js
// I want to do the following
Add<Container, "name", string>
Add<Container, "age", number>

// Here are the results I hope to get
interface Container {
    name: string
    age: number
}
```

Is it possible to implement the above in typescript?

Comment: Interfaces can be [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces). You can write as many `interface Container{}` as you want and all declarations will be merged in `Container`

Comment: The answer to the question *as asked* is "no, this is not possible".  Something of the form `Add<Container, "name", string>` would either be a generic type or possibly an instantiation expression, neither of which would *modify* the `Container` type argument.  Interface merging, as mentioned above, is the closest TS gives you, but you can't abstract over interface merging with generics that way.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I was wondering if it was possible, and since it wasn't possible, it solved the problem，How can I use your comment as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for something of the form `Add<T, K, V>` to *modify* the declaration of the type argument passed in as `T`, whether `Add` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type (e.g., `type Add<T, K, V> = ⋯; type Foo = Add<Container, "name", string>;`) or an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) (e.g., `function Add<T, K, V>(⋯){⋯}; const foo = Add<Container, "name", string>;`)

The only facility TypeScript provides to modify the declaration of an existing interface type is via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), where you re-declare the interface and add new properties to it:

```
interface Container { name: string }
// later
interface Container { age: number }

const c: Container = { name: "abc", age: 123 }; // okay
c.name.toUpperCase(); // okay
c.age.toFixed(); // okay
```

But there is no way to abstract over the declaration merging operation with user-defined code.  I can't find any existing feature request for this in [TypeScript's issue list](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues), so I can't direct you to an authoritative source saying this is impossible.  If one were to file such an issue then we could hear official word from the TypeScript team, but I imagine the issue would be swiftly declined.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtx1NZBvZAXwCgB6U5AGzkimNFviTUzGxFwJDgFsIAuZAGcwUUAHMiZCtVr1w0JigxYcUfMjjiByEAFceAI1wliCTCOQJBKtmuQBeDdz6CARHEMI3AGk3bBAEYAJgBmIgBuZHJkdABrOABPMwA6FwgUsHQAVQAHXOhUOCEIAAoASiiY+KTUrQysgDFgAA8IABMKqooaxKA)